# NoReverseMatch with {% url ... %} and keyword args

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm having a problem with this error:

```
Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for ''pennies.views.seed_preview''
with arguments '()' and
keyword arguments '{'sa': 1724158887L, 'sh': 31L}' not found.
```

which is produced by this bit of template:

```
<a href="{% url 'pennies.views.seed_preview' sh=seed.id sa=seed.salt %}">
Preview</a>
```

and this bit of `url.py`

```
url(r'^seedpreview/sh=(?P<shareable_id>\d+)/sa=(?P<salt>\d+)$', \
    'pennies.views.seed_preview'),
```

and this function signature

```
def seed_preview(request, shareable_id, salt):
```

(and url from future, of course).  And the error suggests to me that django has captured the right dictionary to find my function.  Reading `templatetags/future.py` also leaves me thinking I've done it right, but clearly I haven't.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you are using the wrong keys, it should be

```
{% url 'pennies.views.seed_preview' shareable_id=seed.id salt=seed.salt %}
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought about that, but not so (unless I'm making some other foolish mistake).  

If I say `<a href="{% url 'pennies.views.seed_preview' shareable_id=seed.id salt=seed.salt %}">Preview</a>`,
the results is the (similar) error
`Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for ''pennies.views.seed_preview'' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'shareable_id': 31L, 'salt': 1724158887L}' not found.`

Comment: hm. i notice the double (twice) quotes around the pennies.views.seed_preview. should it maybe not be quoted?

Comment: Oh, man, that works!  Thanks.  But now what's the business of using `{% load url from future %}`, then, in django 1.3?

Comment: i guess you can use that and quote your urls.

Comment: Aha!  I have to specify that in the top level template.  I had requested the load from the base template.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the future url template tag in *every* template where you use it. Loading a template tag library does not make it available to parent or child templates.

For more info see the Django docs on [Custom libraries and template inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#custom-libraries-and-template-inheritance)