# Django, NoReverse Match

Tags: python, django

So I completed my app and there are several models. This particular error comes up only for some values. Example: each user is enrolled to a course and year. So in a page i'm trying to show all the modules that belong to that course for the selected year. When the user is studying at `year 3` it works. When it's `year 2` it throws that error.

```
Reverse for 'module_details_upcoming' with arguments '(10L,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['studies/module/(?P<module_id>\\d)/upcoming/$']
```

In the error page its complaining about `{% url "module_details_upcoming" module.id %}` and I guess also `{% url "module_details_previous" module.id %}`.

Below you can see my code:

views.py

```
def modules(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        user_id = request.user.id

        try:
            studying_course = Student.objects.get(user__id=user_id).course
            studying_year = Student.objects.get(user__id=user_id).year
        except Student.DoesNotExist:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('step2'))

        try:
            modules_list = Module.objects.filter(course=studying_course,year=studying_year).exclude(name="school")
        except Module.DoesNotExist:
            modules_list = None
        # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        return render_to_response("studies/modules.html", {'course': studying_course, 'year': studying_year, 'modules': modules_list,},  RequestContext(request))

    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))

def module_details_upcoming(request, module_id):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        user_id = request.user.id
        dated = True

        try:
            studying_course = Student.objects.get(user__id=user_id).course
            studying_year = Student.objects.get(user__id=user_id).year
        except Student.DoesNotExist:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('step2'))

        try:
            module = Module.objects.get(id=module_id)
        except Module.DoesNotExist:
            module = None

        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        events = Event.objects.filter(module__in=module_id,date__gte=now).order_by('date')

        paginator = Paginator(events, 5)
        try:
            page = int(request.GET.get("page", '1'))
        except ValueError:
            page = 1

        try:
            posts = paginator.page(page)
        except (InvalidPage, EmptyPage):
            posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

        return render_to_response("studies/module.html", {'module': module, 'events': events, 'posts': posts, 'dated': 'dated'},  RequestContext(request))
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^modules/$', 'studies.views.modules', name="modules"),
    url(r'^module/(?P<module_id>\d)/upcoming/$', 'studies.views.module_details_upcoming', name="module_details_upcoming"),
    url(r'^module/(?P<module_id>\d)/previous/$', 'studies.views.module_details_previous', name="module_details_previous"),
)
```

template file:

```
            {% if modules %}
                <p>Below you can find all your modules for this year.</p>
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    <th>Code</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Tasks/Events</th>
                {% for module in modules %}
                    <tbody>
                        <td>{{ module.code }}</td>
                        <td>{{ module.name }}</td>
                        <td><a href="{% url "module_details_upcoming" module.id %}">Upcoming</a> / <a href="{% url "module_details_previous" module.id %}">Previous</a></td>
                    </tbody>
                {% endfor %}
                </table>
            {% else %}
                <p>Oops! It seems that there are no modules for {{ course.name }} in our records. Please contact your school office.</p>
            {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass keyword argument `module_id` in the `url` tag:

```
{% url "module_details_upcoming" module_id=module.id %}
```

Also see this similar problem: [NoReverseMatch with {% url ... %} and keyword args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029820/noreversematch-with-url-and-keyword-args)

UPD: you are actually capturing a single digit in the url. And since for `year 3` `module_id` is `10` (two digits) reverse cannot be completed.

Replace:

```
url(r'^module/(?P<module_id>\d)/upcoming/$', 'studies.views.module_details_upcoming', name="module_details_upcoming"),
url(r'^module/(?P<module_id>\d)/previous/$', 'studies.views.module_details_previous', name="module_details_previous"),
```

with (watch the `\d+` instead of `\d`):

```
url(r'^module/(?P<module_id>\d+)/upcoming/$', 'studies.views.module_details_upcoming', name="module_details_upcoming"),
url(r'^module/(?P<module_id>\d+)/previous/$', 'studies.views.module_details_previous', name="module_details_previous"),
```

Comment: I read this topic and tried it but still nothing. Now it gives the same error and bolts that line in the debug page: `{% url "module_details_upcoming" module_id=module.id %}`. It weird because for `year 3` it works. For `year 2` it does not.

Comment: @ManolisC. ok, but what error does the debug page show?

Comment: `Reverse for 'module_details_upcoming' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'module_id': 10L}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['studies/module/(?P<module_id>\\d)/upcoming/$']` I think it moved `10L` from arguments to keyword arguments.

Comment: @ManolisC. hm, could you show the definition of `module_details_upcoming` view?

Comment: @ManolisC. ok, just to test, what if you replace `def module_details_upcoming(request, module_id):` with `def module_details_upcoming(request, module_id=None):`?

Comment: @ManolisC. another possible fix, try to use `url` tag this way: `{% url module_details_upcoming module_id=module.id %}`. See no quotes around the url name.

Comment: If I remove the quotes i'm getting `'url' requires a non-empty first argument.`

Comment: If I add `=None` i'm getting the same error: `Reverse for 'module_details_upcoming' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'module_id': 10L}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['studies/module/(?P<module_id>\\d)/upcoming/$']`

Comment: @ManolisC. ok, what if you try this way: `{% url 'studies.views.module_details_upcoming' module_id=module.id %}`?

Comment: Then I'm getting `Reverse for 'studies.views.module_details_upcoming' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'module_id': 10L}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['studies/module/(?P<module_id>\\d)/upcoming/$']`

Comment: The thing is that it works for `year 3`. I cannot understand what's wrong with `year 2`.

Comment: Yeap! Now it works! I'm new to django and thought I didn't need to add it. Thank you for spending time on this one!

Comment: @ManolisC. you are welcome. Sorry it took me so long to get the problem - too much tekila for today probably :)

Comment: No worries @alexce! Just figured out some more filtering issues.. I probable need some tequila too! hahaa

Comment: By the way, do I need to one one more `+` in case the events are more than 100?

Comment: @ManolisC. nope `+` means 1 or more.

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you again but I found the issue and I think it has to do with this question. When in this page `http://.../studies/module/10/upcoming/` It shows me the events for the module with id `1`.

Comment: @ManolisC. I think it has to be smth with this line `Event.objects.filter(module__in=module_id,date__gte=now).order_by('date')`. `module_id` is a string `10` at the moment. I doubt you should use `in` here..

Comment: Exactly! I was just about to write it. I remove `__in` and it works!